# Create a vector of type bool, where all values are initialised to true

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far, but 'true' is underlined and says: 
"no suitable constructor exists to convert from "bool" to "std::vector>"

```
vector<bool> choice[512] = {true};
```

Comment: If this compiled, this would create 512 vectors, not one vector with 512 elements.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea: read [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want 1 vector of length 512,  not 512 vectors of length 1 as your code currently does. If so, then:

```
vector<bool> choice(512, true);
```

Note: `vector<bool>` is a specialization that uses 1 bit of storage for each entry, so some of the typical `vector` operations don't work properly. Some people recommend avoiding it entirely.

If you don't need runtime sizing, one alternative is:

```
std::bitset<512> choice;
choice.set();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is

```
vector<bool> choice(512,true);
```

<sub>[See (2) constructor form](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`vector<bool> choice(NUM_ELEMS, true);` will initialize the vector with NUM_ELEM instances of true. In your case, replace this with 512.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ `fill` constructor for reference.